# Aspectj intercept inner class in Scala

Tags: scala, aspectj, inner-classes

How intercept a inner class in Scala using Aspectj annotations?

```
package p
class Ext {
  class Inn {
    def Inner() {}
  }
  def Extern() {}
}

object Main{
def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val res = new Ext
 res.Exter()
 val res2 = new res.Inn
 res2.Inner()
 }
    }

package q
@Aspect
class MethodLogger {
@Before("within(p.*)")
 def logMethod(joinPoint: JoinPoint) = {
   println(joinPoint)
}
}
```

Aspect Code only allows see join points of Main and Ext class but I can not see Inn class join points